# All ports not available with React npm run start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build

So up until yesterday I was able to do npm start no issues.

The versions of things I'm running

```
OSX Mojave...
 npm: '8.19.3',
  node: '19.2.0',
```

Now it is saying that port 3000 is in use. I've done all the tricks to see if 3000 is in use is isn't

changed the port to 3001 3005 4444 and various other and it doesn't work.

Still the same message.

serve -s build works great and runs the app on 3000. no idea what is going on..

```
error message 
✔ Something is already running on port 4001.

Would you like to run the app on another port instead? … no
```

I've tried

```
user@computer >> npx kill-port 4001
Could not kill process on port 4001. No process running on port.
user@computer >>  mtbcrm_react % lsof -i tcp:4001
```

Comment: Please show the whole error message

Comment: You're going to need to supply a lot more information. What commands have you tried to see if the port is running? What happens if you view localhost:3000 in the browser? What's the error message?